# CURL request for AZURE Push Notification is not working

Tags: php, ios, ruby, azure, curl

I have gone through links that provide some `CURL` request samples for `AZURE` push notifications but none of them works for me.

Like in [this](http://www.codeitive.com/7zmyUWVjjP/connect-to-microsoft-push-notification-service-for-windows-phone-8-from-ruby.html) url CURL request using Ruby language is provided but like others it is also not working.

> "Internal Server Error (500)"

occurred every time when I made a request using `CURL` requests.

If anybody can provide me with working code of `CURL` request for `AZURE` push notifications then it would be convenient for me to solve the issue. Keeping in mind that push notifications from web portal of `AZURE` are working absolutely fine.

Comment: _"If anybody can provide me with working code of CURL request for AZURE push notifications then it would be convenient for me to solve the issue."_ SO isn't a place to find tutorials neither are we going to write the code for you. Do some debugging and/or post the code with the error and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

May I know whether you are using Azure Service Bus Notification Hub? If so, the most likely problem from my experience is you may haven't formatted the request properly. It’s needed to prepare the following information, and send them in request headers:

Content-Type: Based on the platform you choose, the value will be different. For instance, for Windows Store apps, content type is application/xml.

ServiceBusNotification-Format: The device type, such as windows.

X-WNS-Type: Push notification type, such as wns/toast.

Authorization: The rules are described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495627.aspx. Pay special attention to the Create SAS Security Token part.

And the request content. The format is different for different devices. For example, for Windows Store apps, it’s needed to use xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><toast><visual><binding template="ToastText01"><text id="1">Hello!</text></binding></visual></toast>
```

If you're using CURL command line, please make sure to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Also please make sure you have correctly registered the push notification service provider in Azure. For instance, for Windows Store apps, please register the SID and the client secret.

If the issue is still encountered, please share more information. It would be better if you can let us know:

•   Are you trying to use the CURL command line or PHP code?
•   What    kind of device you're using?
•   What kind of message you want to    send?

Comment: • I'm using PHP code for CURL request.
• Currently working on iOS device for push notification.
• Push notification message with tag.

Comment: Sorry that I have no IOS device at hand to have a fully test, but per my understanding, the general idea could be the same, you may want to use the iOS's noification format: 
"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello!\"}}"

And check http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-php-backend-how-to/ for a tutorial on how to use CURL in PHP to send notifications to iOS via Azure Notification Hub. Feel free to let us know if you need further assistance.